# How to skip task when condition is not satisfied

Tags: python, ansible, yaml, conditional-statements

Have a role with the following task that is supposed to create a cron job if *my_environment* var is *"prod"*.

I would like the playbook to **skip** this task rather than failing, when the condition is not satisfied:

```
---
- name: Configure cron job to export patch logs
  cron:
    name: export patch logs daily
    minute: 0
    hour: 0
    user: root
    cron_file: patch_logs
    job: "/usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp /var/log/dpkg.log s3://{{ patch_logs_bucket }}/dpkg.log.$(hostname).$(date +\\%F)"
  when: my_environment == "prod"
```

Failure message:

```
TASK [ansible-contxt-base : Configure cron job to export patch logs] ***********
    fatal: [ubuntu-1604]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'scx_environment == \"prod\"' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (scx_environment == \"prod\"): 'my_environment' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/**<path>**/tasks/base.yml': line 125, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Configure cron job to export patch logs\n  ^ here\n"}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use the jinja2 shortcut for 'default(False) ’: 'd(False)’.

```
when: my_environment|d(False) == "prod"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
when:

my_environment is defined

my_environment != ”prod”
```

Comment: some explanation pls

Answer (score 0):

found here https://ansible-docs.readthedocs.io/zh/stable-2.0/rst/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement

```
- shell: echo "This certainly isn't epic!"
  when: not epic
```

or

```
- fail: msg="Bailing out. this play requires 'bar'"
  when: bar is undefined
```